# Laravel 5.3 update request with unique rule with exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-request

I have request for updating page. When adding new page request is like:

```
'title'=>'required|max:70|unique:pages',
```

but when I'm updating page title must be unique but need to check all other titles except one already entered.
I searched Google for all possible solutions but nothing works.

I tried:

```
'title'=>"required|max:70|unique:pages, title,{$this->id}",
'title'=>'required|max:70|unique:pages, title,'.$this->id,
'title'=>'required|max:70|unique:pages, title,'.$this->input('id'),
```

rule is inside rules method

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
    'title'=>'required|max:70|unique:pages, title,'.$this->id,
    ...
    ]
```

I'm getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ' title' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `pages` where ` title` = test and `id` <> )
```

In my mysql I have id (lowercase) column that is primary key and title column (also lowercase).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a bug here:

```
public function rules()
{                                          This space is causing trouble
                                           | 
    return [
    'title'=>'required|max:70|unique:pages, title,'.$this->id,
    ...
    ]
```

Should be

```
public function rules()
{                                          Space removed
                                           | 
    return [
    'title'=>'required|max:70|unique:pages,title,'.$this->id,
    ...
    ]
```

Comment: Yes, now it's not showing any errors but like it doesn't exclude this id. It gives me validation error.
The title has already been taken.

Comment: That depends on what is `$this`, your model has a `rules()` method? If not you are taking the id from the wrong class... So it's a different problem, please open a different question with more information.

Comment: antonio, most likely a form request

Comment: You should `dd($this->id)` to see if this is the same title id

Answer (score 1):

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ' title'
```

It seems that it's searching for a column named " title", it may be stupid but double check that the column name is sent without a space at the beggining.